# Structure using Pointers and Function to store and retrieve data

Tags: c

```
struct account
{
    struct //A structure inside a structure
    {
        char lastName[10];
        char firstName[10];
    } names; //structure is named as 'name'
    int accountNum;
    double balance;
};

int main()
{
    struct account record;
    int flag = 0;
    do
    {
        nextCustomer(&record);
        if ((strcmp(record.names.firstName, "End") == 0) && //only when the first name entered as "End"
                (strcmp(record.names.lastName, "Customer") == 0)) //and last name entered as "Customer", the loop stops
            flag = 1;
        if (flag != 1)
            printCustomer(record);
    }
    while (flag != 1);
}
void nextCustomer(struct account *acct)
{
    printf("Enter names (firstName lastName):\n"); 
    //scanf("%s, %s", acct->firstName, acct->lastName); //have no idea why first and last name cant be found although im aware thats its a structure inside a structure
    printf("Enter account number:\n");
    //scanf("%d", acct->accountNum); 
    printf("Enter balance:\n");
    scanf("%f", acct->balance);
}
void printCustomer(struct account acct)
{
    printf("Customer record: \n");
    printf("%d", acct.accountNum); //can't seem to retrieve data from the strcture
}
```

Hi guys, i am new to c, and i managed to hardcode data on structures, and print our their respective value. Currently, i am working on using a pointer to store the respective data, as well as function to print out their data. Can anyone help me on why i cant store and retrieve my data? I dont need the answers, just the logic flow is sufficient.

Comment: Where are you allocating memory in to store data? I see record getting overwritten again and again. I think you should use an array of accounts instead. By store, do you mean storing it in memory or on disk in a file?

Comment: Rebuild your code with compiler warnings enabled; messages will lead to various missing `&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followin changes are needed to your `nextCustomer` function, you are directly accessing `firstName` and `lastName` using `acct`, but they are present inside `names`

so you have to use `acct->names.firstName` and  `acct->names.lastName`

```
void nextCustomer(struct account *acct)
{
    printf("Enter names (firstName lastName):\n"); 
    scanf("%s%s", acct->names.firstName, acct->names.lastName); //have no idea why first and last name cant be found although im aware thats its a structure inside a structure
    printf("Enter account number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &acct->accountNum); 
    printf("Enter balance:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &acct->balance);
}

void printCustomer(struct account acct)
{
    printf("Customer record: \n");
    printf("F: %s\n", acct.names.firstName);
    printf("L: %s\n", acct.names.lastName);
    printf("A: %d\n", acct.accountNum); //can't seem to retrieve data from the strcture
    printf("B: %lf\n", acct.balance);
}
```

Comment: @Merlina, if that really solves your problem or helps solve your problem please accept the answer.